# How to deep link direct message in telegram

Tags: telegram

I want a deep link to a telegram user and forward a message.

something like this:

`http://t.me/apada?message="hello!"`

in whatsapp i can do this:

`whatsapp://send?text=WHATEVER_YOU_WANT&abid=RECIPIENT_ADDRESSBOOK_ID`

but i want it in telegram too